# Can the Dateadd function be used multiple times in the same query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dateadd

[image]

Can the Dateadd function be used multiple times in the same query (SQL)? I need to set different types of transactions that are processed at different times. I hope I made myself understood
for example, salaries are processed in 1 month, utility payments in 5 days, and so on.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Dateadd is a product specific function.)

Comment: I assume you've attempted to do so, and are seeing some kind of error. It would be really helpful to add a minimal example of your attempt and the error.

Comment: See [mcve] for an example of what we mean by minimal

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEADD((wk, 1, t.DataTranzactie), (mm, 1, t.DataTranzactie), (d, 5, t.DataTranzactie))
```

You can call `DateAdd` multiple times in the same query. But you cannot pass three sets of parameters to a single `DateAdd` call as shown in your screenshot.

[DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql)

At a guess, you want something like:

```
CASE t.IdTripTranzactie
    WHEN 1 THEN DateAdd(wk, 1, t.DataTranzactie)
    WHEN 2 THEN DateAdd(mm, 1, t.DataTranzactie)
    ELSE DateAdd(d, 5, t.DataTranzactie)
END As Data_Procesare
```

Replacing the `WHEN {x}` values with the correct transaction types for your requirements.